# SharePoint Daily Task Checklist

Tags: infopath, form

Really struggling to work this out in my head.

The requirement is as follows:

- We have a checklist template, which I currently have stored in a SP list,  containing 10 items (not tasks) for one department, 12 for another and 13 for another department.

  - This list contains the following fields (Item Name, Feed SLA (time feed should be delivered), Feed Actual, Task SLA (time user should complete task), Task Actual (actual time completed)
  - Requirement is to have an easy to update form (either in InfoPath or SP) so that users can go in, select their department, display only the tasks relevant to their department and then fill out the Actual Times against the SLAs on a daily basis.
  - We then need to store each day's records for each department in Sharepoint so that we can run some MIS at the end of each month on whether users are meeting their deadlines or not.

Does anyone have any idea what the best solution would be. I'm messing around with a repeating table in infoPath at the moment, but going no where as I can pull in the template but not fill out the actual times against the SLAS.

Much obliged!

Answer (score 1):

You can use InfoPath to pull the information, but writing into the list will be more difficult. You either need to use code or the qRules tool from Qdabra software that has commands to write from a browser based form into a SharePoint list.

Another alternative for a parent/child relationship of two SharePoint lists using XSLVs and javascript is outlined in [this blog post](http://geekswithblogs.net/SoYouKnow/archive/2010/12/16/creating-a-sharepoint-parentchild-list-relationshipndash-sharepoint-2010-edition.aspx) at SharePoint Hillbilly. It works, but it's not as pretty as an InfoPath form.